# fabricjs: _render method of my fabric.Object subclass is never called

Tags: render, fabricjs

The initialize method is called but render method is not.
I read about subclassing on [the fabricjs website](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3/) and looked at that [demo](http://fabricjs.com/polaroid/).
I really don't understand what is missing in my code.

```
var CustomCircle = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Object, {

type: "customCircle",

initialize: function (options) {
    this.callSuper('initialize', options);
},

_render: function (ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100, 250, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
    ctx.stroke();

}
});

  var customCircle = new CustomCircle();
  canvas.add(customCircle);
```

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/f6c15qu6/6/)

Comment: It seems to work if I write render instead of _render - I don't understand why...

Comment: Ok, I am not sure if it is a fix or a trick but if I mention the with& height when creating my customCircle then _render is called: new CustomCircle({width:1, height:1}); but it makes nonsense in the code to have width 1 and height 1 while the cercle is much bigger than that... Any comments or answers regarding what I am saying would be useful. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Could you solve this issue? I'm having the same problem at the moment :/

Comment: I posted the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to create a custom object it is up to you to calculate and set the width and height of this latest. To do so you can call **this.set({width: ..., height: ...})** inside the **initialize** function.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var CustomCircle = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Object, {

    radius: 50, 

    type: "customCircle",

    initialize: function (options) {
        this.callSuper('initialize', options);
       this.set({ width: 2 * this.radius, height: 2 * this.radius });
   },

    _render: function (ctx) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0, 0, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
       ctx.stroke();

     }
 });

var customCircle = new CustomCircle({left:50, top:50});

canvas.add(customCircle);
```

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrfrn6wa/3/)

Also note that inside the **_render** function, the canvas has already been translated to the center of your custom object.