# fabricJS - Custom object is not drawn on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm experimenting with custom objects in fabricJS. I'm starting with a line drawed by myself. I know there's already an object for that but I want to understand what happens behind and to what degree I can modify things. So, I'm using a simple line for the beginning but for any reason it's not drawn on the canvas.

It looks like the `_render` function is not called while `initialize` works fine. Can you please tell me what's wrong with my code?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwuw72ov/1/)

```
fabric.CustomLine = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Object, {

    type: 'customline',

    pos : {
        x1 : 0,
        y1 : 0,
        x2 : 0,
        y2 : 0
    },

    initialize: function (options) {
        options = options || {};

        this.callSuper('initialize', options);

        this.pos.x1 = options.x1 || 0;
        this.pos.y1 = options.y1 || 0;
        this.pos.x2 = options.x2 || 0;
        this.pos.y2 = options.y2 || 0;
    },

    _render : function (ctx) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(this.pos.x1, this.pos.y1);
        ctx.lineTo(this.pos.x2, this.pos.y2);
        ctx.closePath();

        this._renderFill(ctx);
        this._renderStroke(ctx);
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565436/fabricjs-render-method-of-my-fabric-object-subclass-is-never-called) there's the same problem. It seems like one has to set `width` and `height` properties to `> 0` but I don't understand why. I can't find this workaround in fabricJS source either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the `_render` function is called by the `Object.render` function.

`Object.render` starts like this:

```
    render: function(ctx, noTransform) {
      // do not render if width/height are zeros or object is not visible
      if ((this.width === 0 && this.height === 0) || !this.visible) {
        return;
      }
     ...
    }
```

Your object does not get any width and height initialized in the `initialize` function and so the `render` method returns immediately and your `_render` function does not get called.