# FabricJS - Render Text for Custom Textbox

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

looking for some advice on how to render text passed into a custom textbox. I'm exploring creating textboxes with different types of borders (circles, diamonds, etc..) and with the below code, I am able to create a cirlce with a textbox inside. However, the text is not showing/rendering to the page.

```js
  addCustom2() {
    let customObj2 = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Textbox, {
      type: 'customObj2',
      radius: 50,
      
      initialize: function(element, options) {
        console.log(this)
        this.callSuper('initialize', element, options);
        this.set({ width: 2 * this.radius, height: 2 * this.radius});
      },
      
      _render: function(ctx) {
        console.log("inside render 2")
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0, 0 , this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    });

    this.canvas.add(new customObj2('Hello', {
      left: 100, 
      top:10,
      fontSize: 21,
      stroke: 'rgba(50,80,220)',
      textAlign: 'center',
      fill: 'rgba(100,80,220)'
    }));
```

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565436/fabricjs-render-method-of-my-fabric-object-subclass-is-never-called) I was able to get the circle to appear, however the text is not showing (here is what I see:)

[image]

By inspecting the element, I am able to see the text change while I type, so I know it is attached to the circle. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

here nice example with text

```
ctx.fillText(this.label, -tw / 2, 0);
```

seems what you are looking for

https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/functions/fabric/IUtil/createClass

Answer (score -1):

Change `_render` to `_renderBackground`.

Comment: there is no _renderBackground in fabricjs API